# Python with reportlab avoid logs when using ImageReader on Flask App

Tags: python, logging, reportlab

I'm using Flask for an application that I need to build some recurrent reporting on .pdf.

But when it comes to build the .pdf and I add some images, when I use the "ImageReader" from reportlab it prints the following logs that I do not want it to print:

```
    2024-02-16 11:31:44,180 STREAM b'IHDR' 16 13
    2024-02-16 11:31:44,180 STREAM b'tEXt' 41 57
    2024-02-16 11:31:44,181 STREAM b'pHYs' 110 9
    2024-02-16 11:31:44,181 STREAM b'IDAT' 131 18719
```

This is the code:

```
    buffer = BytesIO()
    plt.savefig(buffer, format='png')
    buffer.seek(0)
    plot_image = ImageReader(buffer)
    c.drawImage(plot_image, x, y, width=width, height=height)
```

The specific line where the logs appear is:

```
    plot_image = ImageReader(buffer)
```

I've checked everywhere but couldn't find any working response on how to manage it.

Thank you very much for your time

I've already tried:

```
    logging.getLogger('reportlab').setLevel(logging.CRITICAL)
    logging.getLogger('pdfrw').setLevel(logging.CRITICAL)
```

And of course, i'm not looking for a general logging config such as:

```
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.CRITICAL)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be that the logging is not happening in `reportlab` but in `Pillow`, a dependency used for image handling. To confirm exactly where the logging is coming from, change your logging configuration to output the logger name in the log. Then you can do `logging.getLogger(...).setLevel(logging,CRITICAL)` based on the name(s) you find. (For example, the name you find might be `PIL`, or then again it could be something else.)

Comment: That's right! Adding `logging.getLogger('PIL').setLevel(logging.CRITICAL)` solved the issue. Thank you Vinay